# Trying to execute component function after auth.login() with Facebook Auth0 Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services, auth0

I'm trying to execute a component function after Auth0 logs someone in via Facebook authentication. I'm trying to have that component function send a POST request with the Facebook profile object (along with another property I add in) to the ExpressJS server, which then saves it to MongoDB. The problem is, I haven't been able to get it to work. I'm wondering if I could modify the auth.login() function to instead return a promise, and take in a the extra parameter I need, and then subscribe to that from my component, and on success send the object. I've also tried to just put the POST request itself in the Auth Service constructor, but that hasn't worked. Here is my code so far:

home.html

```
...
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" type="submit" (click)="someFunction('extraProperty')">Submit</button>
...
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
import { Auth } from './auth.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private homeService: HomeService, private auth: Auth) { }

  someFunction(extraProperty: string): void {
    // Saving extraProperty to local storage, then authenticating
    localStorage.setItem('extraProperty', extraProperty);
    this.auth.login();
  }
}
```

home.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Auth } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

  constructor (private http: Http) {}
  private serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/';

  // Trying to call this function after Auth Service login
  postVote(body: Object): Observable<Boolean[]> {

    return this.http.post((this.serverUrl + 'postVote'), body)
           .map((res:Response) => {
             console.log("Res is: ", res);
           })
           .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
    // Configure Auth0
    lock = new Auth0Lock('CLIENT_ID', 'DOMAIN');

    userProfile: any;

    constructor(private homeService: HomeService, private http: Http) {

        // Set userProfile attribute of already saved profile
        this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

        // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
        this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

            // Fetch profile information
            this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) => {
                if (error) {
                    // Handle error
                    alert(error);
                    return;
                }
                profile.extraProperty = localStorage.getItem('extraProperty');
                localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
                this.userProfile = profile;
                console.log(profile);


                // Tried calling the service here, but I don't think it would work anyways in the constructor.
                this.homeService.postVote(this.userProfile);

            });
        });
    }

    public login() {
        // Call the show method to display the widget.
        this.lock.show();
    };

    ...
}
```

If I could also go about this in any other way that would be easier that you know of, that would be helpful as well. Essentially I'm trying to get the user's profile, save it to a DB in order to match them up with one person that holds the corresponding extraProperty, redirect to a new module and render the profile pic and name of the person with their match.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the function postVote on the server side. Hope that helps

```
// Adding vote object to MongoDB
router.post('/postVote', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Req.body is: ", req.body);
  Vote.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
      // return err;
    }
    console.log("Vote saved");
  });
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: In the code present in the question the `HomeService.postVote` method is being called after you obtain the user profile which only happens after the user logins because it's a callback for `lock.on("authenticated", ...)`. So what exactly does not work?

Comment: @JoãoAngelo for some reason the HomeService.postVote does not actually perform the POST function. I have edited my post with the proper function that's supposed to handle it on the server side. No errors or anything pop up, but the print statement "Vote saved," does not pop up either.

Comment: If you open the browser network tools do you see any request associated with the `getProfile` or `postVote` actions? If not, the authenticated event is probably not being fired; the best way to troubleshoot this is by using HAR files, but if you do submit one be advised that they will contain sensitive information like passwords and session cookies.